# element-wise multiplication in blockMatrix in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am looking if there is a good way to implement the following problem in Spark BlockMatrix:
Suppose I have a matrix A of n * m, n is huge, and m is not that large, represented by a BlockMatrix. I have another matrix B with only one column, the size is n * 1, also a BlockMatrix. Now I want to multiply these two matrix of A times B, in the way very close to element-wise multiplication. The first row of matrix A will multiply by the first element in matrix B, and so on....
So the result will still be a n * m Matrix. The operation is like B is acting as a weight that put to A.

I think the key is how to mapping the corresponding blocks together.

I know I can make B as a diagonal matrix of n * n, then B * A will be the result. Multiplication is supported already in Spark, but this will not be a good idea since it costs much more in communication.

Comment: solved it already

Comment: Can you share the answer then please? Answering your own questions is fine,  I think